# How do you initialise an array of const values in D2?

Tags: arrays, initialization, const-correctness, d

Essentially, I want to be able to do something like this:

```
struct Foo
{
  const(int)[2] ints;

  this(int x, int y)
  {
    ints = [x, y];
  }
}
```

but this doesn't work. The compiler (DMD 2.048) just complains that `ints` isn't mutable.

How are you supposed to initialise the array?

Comment: if you define ints as dynamic array:

const(int)[] ints;

the assignment works as expected - you should be able to rebind ints. The question is if the behavior is defined to be the same for static arrays, if yes, then it is a bug.

Comment: Well I imagine it should be, otherwise there would be no way to have a static array of `const` values.

Comment: Asked for clarification on d newsgroups http://www.digitalmars.com/pnews/read.php?server=news.digitalmars.com&group=digitalmars.D.learn&artnum=21538

Comment: it is not a bug. Static array (ints) is value type and does not have any indirections, so types const(int)[2] and const(int[2]) have same behavior - unlike dynamic arrays.

Comment: Michal, you asked a completed unrelated question on the news group. My question is about initialisation, not rebinding. They are completely different things. Obviously you can't rebind a const array (it's const!), but you should be able to initialise it (otherwise, why have a type at all if you can't use it!?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to implement constructor is this way:

```
  this(int x, int y) 
  {
    auto i2 = cast(int[2]*)&ints;
    *i2 = [x, y];
  }
```

const is readonly view, so the constructor creates mutable view `i2` and assign to it. I really don't like the cast in first line, maybe there is some function in std lib that encapsulates the cast and removes const modifier from type of variable, so this can be expressed in safe and idiomatic manner.

Second way is to make `ints` mutable and private, then provide public accessor function:

```
struct Foo {

  private int[2] _ints;

  this(int x, int y) {
      _ints = [x, y];
  }

  @property ref const(int)[2] ints () {
      return _ints;
  }
}
```

Compiler may be able to inline it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Note that I didn't actually intend for it to be publicly visible -- I was just keeping the code simple to illustrate the problem :)

Comment: You meant good, but you did bad - I'm pretty sure you very well know that increased code visibility increases program complexity ;)